# Vector handling bullets in DirectX

Tags: c++, stl, vector, directx

I have a vector to hold objects of a bullet class.  Is this the correct way to add bullets to the vector structure?

```
std::vector<Bullet> bullets;

Bullet newbullet(thisPlayer.x+PLAYERSPRITEWIDTH,(thisPlayer.y-(PLAYERSPRITEHEIGHT/2)));
bullets.push_back(newbullet);
```

I don't think the bullets get added this way.

Comment: What makes you think the bullets aren't getting added?  Is the `bullets` collection empty?  Are you getting exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a perfectly valid way to add "Bullet"s to a std::vector.

Make sure your vector is defined outside of the scope of the function.  Otherwise the vector drops out of scope and is deallocated.

Some links that may help your understanding a bit:
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've figured it out now.